# How to create a project with the same package name and SHA-1 key I've already used in my recently deleted project in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, sha1

Here, while trying Firebase Authentication it is showing me some error message.

```
An OAuth2 client already exists for this package name and SHA-1 in another project
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow these steps:

- Ensure that your project was actually deleted and the SHA-1 key isn't used in another project
- Create a new project, with another name (different from the one that you already deleted it)
- Change the name of the new created project with the name of the project you deleted.
- Add the SHA-1 key
- Download the JSON file and copy it in the coresponding place
- Run your project